# How to limit process usage (user or process)

Tags: php, linux

I need help with a problem:

I have a PHP code and it runs multiple times with multiple files and that is using the processor a lot and consequently bringing the server down. I would like to limit the processor usage for this user to the less possible, making it stop crashing the server and runs untill it ends. Even if it runs very slowly, the important thing is that it finishes without the server going down.

Anyone have any idea?

Already limit it bt  /etc/security/limits.conf

```
@user hard core 10000
```

But I had no result.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux system you can use [proc_nice](http://php.net/proc_nice) to reduce the priority of the script

Also, you can add a `sleep(1)` function somewhere in your code (for example in a big/infinit loop)
sleeping for 1 second is like a year for a processor :)